# Downloading a file that may take a long time to request

Tags: c#, asp.net, http

I have an application that generates 50,000 records containing certain information.  Once generated and saved to the database, the user can download the records as csv any time they like from a control panel.

The problem I am getting is that it can take anything up to 40+ seconds to generate the CSV.  But by the time its finished processing, the browser no longer tries to download it.  Instead it just hangs.

I have currently set a high timeout value so the processing won't timeout.  Also I need to it be generated on the fly as it needs to contain related live data in with it.

Does anyone know why it doesn't download after waiting for the file to generate?

Heres the headers I respond with once generated:

```
//**generate the csv as string here, and then...**
Response.Clear();
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", string.Format("attachment;filename=file_{0}.csv", batchId));
Response.ContentType = "text/csv";
Response.Write(csv);
Response.End();
```

Comment: From MSDN: Remarks - The Clear method does not clear header information.  Try `Response.ClearHeaders()`.

Comment: Thats right.  I just wanted to make sure the response is clear before I write the csv.  As far as I am aware, clear removes anything that has been written to the response?

Comment: Yes, but often the headers will also have strange things lurking around that you'll want to get rid of.

Comment: Another option would be to use an update panel with a timer which would check with the server to see if the file has been generated.  The update panel would say something like "Please wait, generating file."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't generate the entire csv file up front. Write records to the stream as you retrieve them from the database. You want code that looks something like this:

```
Response.Clear();
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", string.Format("attachment;filename=file_{0}.csv", batchId));
Response.ContentType = "text/csv";

using (SqlDataReader rdr= GetDataForCSV())
{
    int i = 0;
    while (rdr.Read())
    {
       Response.Write(CSVFromIDataRecord(rdr));
       Response.Write("\n");
       if (i % 50 == 0)
       {
           //flush the output stream every now and then
           Response.Flush();
       }
    }
    rdr.Close();
}
Response.End();
```

Note that I don't advocate this exact code. For example, there are some issues using an SqlDataReader in this way that fall outside the scope of the question. You'll also want to set up the number of records between each flush call such that you take good advantage of your IIS server's response buffer, depending on your specific average record size. I would make some other changes in production as well, but this should be enough to point you in the right direction.

Comment: Perfect!  I think I am having one of those "I never thought of that!" moments :-)

Comment: It also reduced the processing time to around 3 seconds compared to generating it and then writing to the buffer.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to increase keep-alive timeout. In general - yours server should reply faster.

[How to change the default keep-alive time-out value in Internet Explorer](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/813827)